# Visual basic: look for opened Excel files and select it

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I want VBA to look for a file with the name "YYYYMMDDorders.csv" and select that file.

So when "20140522orders.csv" is opened, it should find that file.

This is my code:

```
Sub controle()
    Dim intSrcColNr As Integer
    Dim strSheetname As String
    Dim strWorkbookname As String

    Dim strCsv As String
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strSheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    strWorkbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Look for YYYYMMDDOrders.csv in open Excel files:

```
For Each wkb In Workbooks
    If InStr(1, wkb.Name, "Orders.csv") <> 0 Then
        strCsv = wkb.Name
    End If
Next
```

Select CSV file:

```
On Error GoTo CSVerror
Windows(strCsv).Activate
```

If csv file isn't opened.

```
    CSVerror:
    MsgBox "File: " & strCsv & ".csv not open"
    Sheets("procédure").Select
End Sub
```

Although I opened the CSV file, it displays the error: "File: 20140522Orders.csv.csv not open".

What am I missing here? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Unless `If csv file isn't opened.` represents some code, the routine drops straight from the `Activate` to the display of the error message.  If you add `Debug.Print "Activate OK"` `Exit Sub` in this gap, "Acivate OK" displays instead of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You missed something: if you tag a line as `CSVError` it doesn't mean that the code is executed until there/is not executed until the `End Sub`. If you need to handle the Error that way, you could insert an `End` right before the `CSVError` line, so that if the file is open, the program would stop there, otherwise jump to `CSVError` and stop at `End Sub`.

```
Sub controle()

Dim intSrcColNr As Integer
Dim strSheetname As String
Dim strWorkbookname As String
Dim strCsv As String
Dim wkb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strSheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
strWorkbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

For Each wkb In Workbooks
    If InStr(1, wkb.Name, "Orders.csv") <> 0 Then
        strCsv = wkb.Name
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo CSVerror
Windows(strCsv).Activate
End

CSVerror:
MsgBox "File: " & strCsv & " not open"
Sheets("procédure").Select

End Sub
```

Better would be NOT to handle an error but to `If`/`Else` the possibility that Orders.csv never appears:

```
For Each wkb In Workbooks
    If InStr(1, wkb.Name, "Orders.csv") <> 0 Then
        strCsv = wkb.Name
    End If
Next

If strCsv = "" Then
    MsgBox "File: " & strCsv & " not open"
    Sheets("procédure").Select
Else
    Windows(strCsv).Activate
End If
```